# Kmeans clustering with heatmaps

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

Just wondering but how would you go about using k means clustering for this data set?
I am restricted from using any packages or modules.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gsprint23/cpts215/master/progassignments/files/simple.csv

This data set is training for this one

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gsprint23/cpts215/master/progassignments/files/cancer.csv

Have been trying to solve this for a while, tried a couple things but none of them seemed to have worked. No code is required but if someone could give me a general thought process to solve this I'd be very grateful.

This was my current way of thinking. I'm trying to put his data into a heatmap
My current thought process was to first randomly choose the centers.
Then create a list of lists for each point for the distance to each center.
Find the index of the minimum distance for each point for each center.
Create a data frame of the same size as the data set and fill each index for each element with the index of the center the point is closest to.
Recompute the center by taking the mean of the points with the same center index
Repeat this process multiple times until the index data frame does not change.
Create a new data frame and add the points which have the same center point close together in the frame.
Then create the heatmap.

This did not seem to work though.
Just wondering, am I on the right track or am I completely off, and if I am on the right track which parts would I need to change in order to fix the issue. If not could you please point me on the right track.

Here is the code to look at

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import random
#%matplotlib inline

def truncate(f, n):
    return math.floor(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n

def chooseCenter(data, centers):
    length = data.shape
    cent = []
    while len(cent) < centers :
        x = random.randrange(0,length[0])
        y = random.randrange(0,length[1])
        if data.iloc[x][y] not in cent:
            d = truncate(data.iloc[x][y],2)
            cent.append(d)
    return cent


def distance(val, center):
    return math.sqrt((val- center)**2)


def getDistances(centers, data):
    length = data.shape
    dist = []
    for i in range(length[0]):
        for j in range(length[1]):
            y = []
            for k in range(len(centers)):
                val = distance(data.iloc[i][j], centers[k]) 
                y.append(truncate(val,3))
            dist.append(y)
    return dist

def findClosest(data, dist):
    close = data.copy()
    length = close.shape
    indexes = []
    for i in range(len(dist)):
        pt = min(dist[i])
        idx = dist[i].index(pt)
        indexes.append(idx)
    #print(indexes)
    length = data.shape
    n = np.array(indexes)
    n = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(n, (length[0],length[1])))
    #reshape this data frame into the same shape as the data
    #keep running the find closest until there is no change
    #try heatmap on this?
    #this should cluster it, but to make sure test it
    #might need to do some tweaking to this

    return n
#    for i in range(length[0]):
#        for j in range(length[1]):
#            print('dist[i]', dist[j])
#            pt = min(dist[j])
#            print(pt)
#            idx = dist[j].index(pt)
#            close.iloc[i][j] = int(idx)
    #return close

def computeNewCenter(data, close):
    d = dict()
    for i in range(len(close)):
        for j in range(len(close[0])):
            d[close.iloc[i][j]] = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[0])):
            if close.iloc[i][j] in d:
                d[close.iloc[i][j]].append(data.iloc[i][j])
    newCenters = []

    for key, value in d.items():
        m = np.mean(value)
        newCenters.append(truncate(m, 3))

    return newCenters
#    lst = [[] * numcenters]
#    for i in range(len(close)):
#        for j in range(len(close[0])):
#            if close.iloc[i][j]


def main():
    data = np.array(pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gsprint23/cpts215/master/progassignments/files/simple.csv',  header=None))
    data = data.T
    #print(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0], dtype=float).T
    df = df.iloc[::-1]
#    print(df)
#    print(df.iloc[1][9])
#    print(df)
#    print(df.iloc[0][1])
#    heatmap = plt.pcolor(df, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)
#    plt.colorbar(heatmap)
    c = chooseCenter(df, 3)
    print(c)
    #print(len(c))
    dist = getDistances(c, df)
    #print(dist)
    y = findClosest(df, dist)
#    q = []
#    for i in range(len(c)):
#        q.append([])
#    #print(q)
    j = computeNewCenter(df, y)
    #print(j)
    length = df.shape
    oldFrame = pd.DataFrame(np.ndarray((length[0],length[1])))
    oldFrame = oldFrame.fillna(0)
    ct=0
    while y.equals(oldFrame) == False:
        ct+=1
        oldFrame = y.copy()
        c = computeNewCenter(df, oldFrame)
        #print(c)
        dist = getDistances(c, df)
        #print(dist)
        y = findClosest(df, dist)
        #print(y)
    #plt.pcolor(df, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)

    l = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(y[0])):
            if y.iloc[i][j] == 1:
                l.append(df.iloc[i][j])

    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(y[0])):
            if y.iloc[i][j] == 2:
                l.append(df.iloc[i][j])
    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(y[0])):
            if y.iloc[i][j] == 0:
                 l.append(df.iloc[i][j])


    l = np.ndarray((length[0],length[1]))
    l = pd.DataFrame(l)
    print(l)
    hm = plt.pcolor(l, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)
    plt.colorbar(hm)    
#    print(y)
#    print(c)
#    print(ct)
    #plt.pcolor(y, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: Are you somehow restricted form using `sklearn` or `tensorflow`?

Comment: Your *dataset* has 6 data points only? How many clusters are you expecting to find? As @DanielF mentions, if you just want `kmeans`, use scikit-learn, tensorflow, scipy or any other library, don't code again what is already out there.

Comment: For my assignment I'm supposed to implement it by myself, the data set is just a test one, the actual data set is this one which is much bigger https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gsprint23/cpts215/master/progassignments/files/cancer.csv